# How to Pass/POST ArrayList in ApiInterface Android when Passing Array in Form Data Postman

Tags: android, json, arraylist, retrofit, postman

[Check this Image Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pbNm.png)I am passing Array in Postman form data. Now I want to POST data from Android to Server using Retrofit. Here I mentioned my ApiInterface and Postman Response.Please tell me that How to write method for that in ApiInterface.

I have tried below code

```
  @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("reserve_seat")
    Call<ResSeatResponse> getReserveSeat(@Header("UserId") String Userid,
                                         @Field("facility_id") Integer facilityId,
                                         @Field("seat_numbers[]") ArrayList<String> seatNumbers,
                                         @Field("time_id") Integer timeId,
                                         @Field("amount") String amount);
```

Response is coming null

Comment: just remove the [] from the seatNumbers filed key @shah

Comment: @RamzyHassan I also tried that but it is not working. Response is coming null

Comment: can you pass a list instead of arraylist @Shah

Comment: @RamzyHassan I tried List. But Not working